# Monthly data in highcharts without explicitly providing all month label

Tags: highcharts

I have very simple array to be plotted, monthly, starting from Jan'10.

Following is my data. `0` is for `Jan'10`, `1` for `feb'10` and so on.

```
data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

I used the following code, to plot the graph ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v85xq9oe/2/)).

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000*30 // 30 days
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
    }]
});
```

This worked fine just one problem.

**Problem:**

Because I have given time interval to be 30days, second point is having x coordinate to be 31 Jan (instead of expected 1 feb).

Is there a way to tell highcharts that my data is monthly.

One solution I know that will work is explicitly giving each coordinate to highchart as [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/).

```
 xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
```

But I found out [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/) graph which has yearly data automatically plotted by highcharts without explicitly being given all years on x-axis, explicitly, I am sure there must be a way to do this for monthly data as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `pointIntervalUnit` to `month`:

```
series: [{
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
    pointIntervalUnit: 'month',
    data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
}]
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vezdp4nf/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.pointIntervalUnit